# CMake Error at ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake:41 (message)

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, ros-humble

Env:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- ROS2 humble
- autoware.universe

I am trying to create a workspace for Autoware.universe in Docker, but there are some issues during the build process.

After I executed

`colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

The error message is

```
MAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release 
Starting >>> ament_cmake_core
Starting >>> ndt_omp
--- stderr: ament_cmake_core                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/autoware/src/universe/external/ament_cmake/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ament_package.templates import get_environment_hook_template_path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package'
CMake Error at ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake:41 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3.10
  /autoware/src/universe/external/ament_cmake/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py
  /autoware/build/ament_cmake_core/ament_cmake_package_templates/templates.cmake)
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (include)


---
Failed   <<< ament_cmake_core [1.04s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< ndt_omp [1.03s]
                                  
Summary: 0 packages finished [5.39s]
  1 package failed: ament_cmake_core
  1 package aborted: ndt_omp
  2 packages had stderr output: ament_cmake_core ndt_omp
  362 packages not processed
```

I cloned src files via `vcs import src < autoware.repos`,
so I don't think there are files missing.
Maybe I should add some path or something else?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package'
```

usually indicates that you did not properly source your ROS2 install.  Execute the following before you run `colcon build`.

```
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
cd <your ros2 workspace path>
colcon build --symlink-install
```

If you are using docker you can add something like this to your dockerfile

```
RUN bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash ;  colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
```